# Help installing vim fuzzyfinder plugin

Tags: vim, vi

This plugin ([here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984)) looks really great but whenever I try to install it vim doesnt seem to recognize that it exists.

I unzip the archive in my .vim dir but when I run vim and try to execute a fuzzyfinder command I get a command not found error.

```
E492: Not an editor command: FufBuffer
```

Here are the contents of my .vim dir

```
bash-3.2$ ls -R .vim
.vim:
autoload  doc  plugin  syntax  vim-fuzzyfinder.zip

.vim/autoload:
fuf  fuf.vim

.vim/autoload/fuf:
bookmark.vim  callbackfile.vim  dir.vim   givencmd.vim  givenfile.vim  mrufile.vim     tag.vim
buffer.vim    callbackitem.vim  file.vim  givendir.vim  mrucmd.vim     taggedfile.vim

.vim/doc:
fuf.jax  fuf.txt  vcscommand.txt

.vim/plugin:
fuf.vim  fuzzyfinder.vim  vcsbzr.vim  vcscommand.vim  vcscvs.vim  vcsgit.vim  vcshg.vim  vcssvk.vim  vcssvn.vim

.vim/syntax:
CVSAnnotate.vim  gitAnnotate.vim  SVKAnnotate.vim  SVNAnnotate.vim  vcscommit.vim
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Checking $VIMRUNTIME is definitely a good idea. However after checking that I ended up emailing the author Takeshi Nishida to ask if he had any ideas.

Apparently the latest version of FuzzyFinder requires vim 7.2! I guess I missed that in the install notes but after making sure I was on 7.2 it worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to unpack it inside your vim runtime directory. This is stored in the environment variable `$VIMRUNTIME`. Even though yours sounds correct, see what is reported by this:

```
cd $VIMRUNTIME;pwd
```

also check permissions on the files.

Answer (score 1):

The install notes implies you need to put these files in "your runtime".  This person is not a native english speaker - they might be assuming $VIMRUNTIME. Or maybe not.  I would have put it in my home are too.  Try $VIMRUNTIME.

Does `:help :fuf` return anything?